# Authenticate an app and get the access token in flattr api v2

Tags: flattr

I am a bit stuck in authenticating my app and get an access token, when following this instructions: http://developers.flattr.net/v2/

Step 1, Authenticate works fine. I get back the code, and my app is listed in my Settings/Applications with the correct scope.

Then I try to get the access token via the following curl command:

```
curl -v --user MY_KEY:MY_SECRET -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
-X POST -d '{"grant_type": "authorization_code",\
"redirect_uri": "http://localhost/", "code": "MY_CODE"}'\
https://flattr.com/oauth/token
```

Unfortunately I always get "invalid_request"

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=500
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=d9972s9r5a7t4p0ch4chc4dqh2; path=/; domain=.flattr.com; HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 291
< Connection: close
< Date: Wed, 16 Nov 2011 22:38:30 GMT
< Server: lighttpd
< 
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter or parameter value, repeats a parameter, includes multiple credentials, utilizes more than one mechanism for authenticating the client, or is otherwise malformed."}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I added the newlines only for better readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bug in the process and it is now smashed. Should be working smooth if you try the request again!

Comment: Thanks Simon, but I still get the same error. Maybe my request is really incomplete, but I don't see where!?

Comment: Yeah... Working now. Thank you :)